# Winlogon Event ID 811/812 event tags

Tags: windows, event-log, forensics, winlogon.exe

In the Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon/Operationsl.evtx event log, event IDs 811 and 812 record the start and end of Winlogon events. The `Data` tag named `Event` specifies the session event type, e.g. in the linked screenshot the '5' circled indicates a system unlock:
[winlogon event example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcXX2.png)

I understand that there are some known event tags:
2 = logon,
3 = logoff,
4 = lock (regardless of automatic or manual),
5 = unlock,
6 = screensaver start,
7 = screensaver stop

However, I have also seen examples which are not documented elsewhere. Is anyone able to explain what these event tags are:

0,
1,
8,
9,
10,
11,
12,
13